# Two prices page Product

Tags: magento-1.8, price, custom-options

I've been a while seeing as I can do the following, currently in my product page when any amount is selected and customized options dynamically calculates my total price up there perfect, but I need, give me the price of one unit also with the same options to know the cost of a unit:

example: product 100 + custom options = 135 € (100und) 1.35 € (1 Unit) .

How can I get this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create one attribute from:

> Manage Attribute>Create Attribute

Then drag/drop that attribute to your attribute set:

> Manage Attributes Set

Make sure you use correct values for creating attribute and also

> Visible of product view page>True

Then your attribute will be visible on frontend.

You can follow this [Link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields), to have more knowledge for this.

Comment: Sorry, I think I have not explained well, I want the price of a unit with custom options like the total price of selected units and show the two prices at a time is dynamically updated.